# Combinatorics - arranging people in a circle with a condition

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Adam has 12 children
In how many ways we can arrange his children around a circle table if Josh cannot sit next to Mark?

My solution to this is:
The total number of permutations for a circle is: $(n-1)!$

Hence, $11!$.
From this we'll subtract all the combinations that Josh sits next to Mark. We'll calculate this by "sticking" them together and treating them as one entity, hence: $10!$

So the final answer is: $11!-10!$

Is this right? Is there any way of solving this better?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One way is $11! - 10!2!$, such that $11!$ is the all possible permutations in a circle, $10!$ is all possible permutations in a circle when Josh and Mark are sitting together, and $2!$ is their permutations, i.e., {Josh, Mark} or {Mark, Josh}.

Answer (score 1):

Seat Josh ($1$ way since it's a circle).

Seat Mark away from Josh ($9$ ways).

Seat the remaining $10$ kids ($10!$ ways).

Total: $9\cdot 10!$

This agrees with user230329's answer with a slightly different approach.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your answer is absolutely correct and is the best possible way to solve the question.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/538986)

Comment: The proposed answer is incorrect.  See the other solutions.

Comment: @MichaelMedvinsky: Many new users who begin reviewing make this mistake: the answer above *does* answer the question, it just does so in a very poor way. A reviewer should not vote to delete answers based on their mathematical content (he should downvote if necessary), but only based on the formal aspect of the answer. From a *purely formal* point of view this answer is all right, so it may stay.